# Beta function of $\phi^4$ from RG equation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, renormalization, regularization, effective-field-theory

I am currently following David Tongs lecture notes on statistical field theory [(Link to the script)](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html) and I have an issue with the calculation of the beta-function from the RG equations (equation (3.45)). For the $\phi^4$ model

$$S[\phi] = \int d^4x \ \frac{1}{2}\left(\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \phi + \mu_0^2 \phi^2\right) + g_0 \phi^4$$

He first derives the RG equations for $\mu$ and $g$ in second order in $g_0$ (neglecting terms that he deems less significant):

$$\mu^2(\lambda) = \lambda^2(\mu_0^2 + ag_0) \ , \quad 
g(\lambda) = g_0 - bg_0^2$$

where
$$a = 12 \int_{\Lambda/\lambda}^\Lambda \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{1}{q^2 + \mu_0^2} \ ,\quad 
 b = 36 \int_{\Lambda/\lambda}^\Lambda \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{1}{(q^2 + \mu_0^2)^2}.$$

$\Lambda$ denotes the momentum cut-off and the expressions result from integrating out
the field modes $\phi_k$ corresponding to momentum $ \Lambda/\lambda \leq k \leq \Lambda$.
He then introduces a new variable $s = \ln(\lambda)$ and argues that derivatives of the
form

$$\frac{d}{ds}\int_{\Lambda e^{-s}}^\Lambda dk \ f(k) = \Lambda f(\Lambda)$$

can easily be calculated. Therefore we should have

$$\frac{da}{ds} = \frac{3}{2\pi^2} \frac{\Lambda^4}{\Lambda^2 + \mu_0^2} \ ,\quad 
 \frac{db}{ds} = \frac{9}{2\pi^2} \frac{\Lambda^4}{(\Lambda^2 + \mu_0^2)^2}.$$

Then he proceeds to calculate the beta functions

$$\beta_{\mu^2}(s) = \frac{d\mu^2(s)}{ds} \overset{?}{=} 2\mu(s)^2 + \frac{3g(s)}{2\pi^2}\frac{\Lambda^4}{\Lambda^2 + \mu(s)^2} \ , \quad 
\beta_{g}(s) = \frac{dg(s)}{ds} \overset{?}{=} -\frac{9}{2\pi^2}\frac{\Lambda^4}{(\Lambda^2 + \mu(s)^2)^2}\cdot g(s)^2$$

However, by using the above expression I arrive at

$$\beta_{\mu^2}(s) = \frac{d\mu^2(s)}{ds} = 2\mu(s)^2 + e^{2s}\frac{3g_0}{2\pi^2}\frac{\Lambda^4}{\Lambda^2 + \mu_0^2} \, \quad 
\beta_{g}(s) = \frac{dg(s)}{ds} = -\frac{9}{2\pi^2}\frac{\Lambda^4}{(\Lambda^2 + \mu_0^2)^2}\cdot g_0^2.$$

I See how one could write $g(s)^2 = g_0^2 + O(g_0^3)$ but for $\mu$ the situation seems to be more complicated. How does one arrive at David Tongs results, starting from mine (or vice versa, why are they equivalent up to the order of approximation).